# editable table cell take value on enter press?

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a table with the purpose of keeping track of the score of a real game. Therefore, thinking that you might input the wrong value I've made the cells editable. My question is what can I do so when I input a value and press enter to simply take the value and not add an extra row?

Also I would add that I would like not to be able to input other things than numbers.

My markup looks something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td contentEditable="true" class="center"><?php echo($score_u1)?><i class="icon-heart pull-right"></i><i class="icon-flag pull-right"></i></td>
    <td contentEditable="true" class="center"><?php echo($score_u2)?></td>
    <td contentEditable="true" class="center">0</td>
    <td contentEditable="true" class="center">0</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted. Code isn't great, but only took me couple minutes to do, hope this gives you ideas and you can polish(improve) rest yourself. Note: you need jQuery imported for this.
Here is link to try it out:
https://jsfiddle.net/bigneo/s4yksmby/1/

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Team 1</td>
        <td>Team 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="t1" type="text"></input>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="t2" type="text"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#t1').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==13){
          if(isNaN(this.value)){
                this.select();   
            }
            else{
                $('#t2').focus();
                $('#t2').select();   
            }    
        }
    });

    $('#t2').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==13){
            if(isNaN(this.value)){
                this.select();   
            }
            else{
          $('#t1').focus();
                $('#t1').select();   
            }   
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! This is exactly what I needed! Much appreciated!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. You can add CSS stilling to it if you need to make it look pretty.